# Howto automatically add a specific value from current route to all generated links?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have site culture in URLs like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default", 
    "{language}/{controller}/{action}/{id}", 
    languageDefaults, 
    languageConstraints)
```

And it works like a charm with a little help from custom MvcHttpHandler that sets current thread's UI culture on every request based on route value. My problem is how do I automatically add the language route value from current request to all outgoing links? E.g. when page /EN/Foo/Bar is requested, I would like this

```
<%=Html.ActionLink(
    "example link", 
    MVC.Home.Index()) %>
```

To automatically generate the same result as this:

```
<%=Html.ActionLink(
    "example link", 
    MVC.Home.Index()
        .AddRouteValue(
            "language", 
            this.ViewContext.RouteData.Values["language"]) %>
```

And of course the same for all other helpers like BeginForm() etc. In my current code base there are already > 1000 occasions where these helpers are used, and requiring .AddRouteValue every time is very fragile as some developer will forget to use it with 100 % certainty.

I hope the only solution is not creating custom Html helpers for everything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should preserve all values defined in route and present in `RouteData` automatically, unless you set it to something else. Try to create link without T4MVC or check your route definitions. Something like this works for me just fine:

```
routes.MapRoute("Default with language", "{lang}/{controller}/{action}/{id}", new
{
    controller = "Home",
    action = "Index",
    id = UrlParameter.Optional,
}, new { lang = "de|fr" });
routes.MapRoute("Default", "{controller}/{action}/{id}", new
{
    controller = "Home",
    action = "Index",
    id = UrlParameter.Optional,
    lang = "en",
});
```

+

```
protected void Application_AcquireRequestState(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MvcHandler handler = Context.Handler as MvcHandler;
    if (handler == null)
        return;

    string lang = (string)handler.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["lang"];

    CultureInfo culture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(lang);

    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = culture;
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = culture;
}
```

+

```
<%: Html.ActionLink("About us", "Detail", "Articles", new { @type = ArticleType.About }, null) %>
```

Comment: Strange, very strange: this was how I expected it to work, but it didn't. Now I created a vanilla test project and you are right, it really works as you write. There must be something in my project that breaks this behavior (the first suspect is T4MVC).

Comment: T4MVC was not the reason, but a pure and simple bug: I had language change links on the master page. When rendering those links list of available languages was looped through, and during the loop current route was mistakenly altered.