# ASP.NET, MVC, C# website pass a value though out the application

Tags: asp.net-mvc

This is a bit of a puzzle for me.

I need to capture the URI Query string passed to the Home page.

As a user travels to different pages on the web site, I have a partial view that needs that URI query string.

I need a dynamicly created link in the partial view, that equals the original call to the home page.

Example -

If the user goes to - `http://www.mysite.com?mode=Joe` , I need the dynamicly created link to equal - `Http://www.mysite.com?mode=Joe`

If the user goes to - `http://www.mysite.com?mode=Tommy` , I need the dynamicly created link to equal - `Http://www.mysite.com?mode=Tommy`

FYI - The partial view is used in the `_Layout.cshtml` file. the call inside - `_Layout.cshtml` looks like this -

```
@Html.Partial("MyPartial")
```

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you just cache the value in a session variable and pass it on that way?

Comment: Just make your home action method take a `string` parameter called `mode`, then put it in your model, then pass that model down to your view, then to your partial view?

Comment: Hey mattytommo, can I access the model in the partial view with the way it is being called - (@Html.Partial("MyPartial"))? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of ways to do this, but probably the simplest would be to save it to the session on your home page, and then access that session variable from your partial.

You will need to decide what to do if the session expires.

Another possible way would be to write it to a cookie on the home page request and then access the request cookie in your partial.  Again, you'd need to decide on an approach for cookies disabled, or wiped out during browsing.

---

Alternatively, you could look at something like the approach being used in the link below to set a language across the site.  Exact implementation would differ, but concept is the same:

[Howto automatically add a specific value from current route to all generated links?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5060346/howto-automatically-add-a-specific-value-from-current-route-to-all-generated-lin)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Paddy! (and the link!)